# randTest () method that takes a single int n as an argument

Tags: java, random, count, int, increment

Below are the instructions that i must follow for the code, i have done most of the code but i seem to be missing elements that make it compile correctly.

A static void method named randTest that takes a single integer argument, n. This should perform the following actions:

- Declare an int array of 10 elements named counts. This will be used to record how often each possible value is returned by randInt.
- Call randInt n times, each time incrementing the count of the element of counts corresponding to the value returned.

  ```
  public static void randTest(int n){
  int [] counts = new int [10];
  int sampleSize = 10000;
  //int n = sampleSize;
  int RandNum = RandInt();

  System.out.println ("Sample Size: " + sampleSize);
  String[] intArray = new String[] {"Value","Count","Expected","Abs Diff","Percent Diff"};
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));



  for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
      counts[ RandNum ] = counts[ RandNum ] + 1;
      counts[i] = RandInt();
      System.out.println(counts[n]);
      } 
  }
  ```

The information must then be printed out into a results table like so:

[image]

Comment: what is you problem?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: There are many problems in your code : the non-respect of CamelCase, the poor naming (`intArray` for an array of strings), the number of random numbers generated, the way they are counted etc

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting exactly when compiling?

First, your `counts` size is only 10 so you cannot do `counts[i]` as `i` could be up to 10,000.

You commented out `int n` so you cannot `System.out.println(counts[n]);`

`int RandNum = RandInt();`, you'll have to limit this or change it since `counts` is only size 10.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing counts right, but why do you change the value of counts[i] after? You also need to get a new random number every time through the for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(10);
    counts[ randomNum ] = counts[ randomNum ] + 1;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem come from the `for`

```
public static void randTest(int n){
  int [] counts = new int [10];

  String[] intArray = new String[] {"Value","Count","Expected","Abs Diff","Percent Diff"};
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));



  for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    int randomNumber = RandInt();
    counts[ randomNumber ] = counts[ randomNumber ] + 1;
    System.out.println("Added one to value : " + randomNumber);
  } 
}
```

You had `counts[i] = RandInt();` thats break everithing cause i can be greater than the size of the array.
Plus you were never changing the value of the random number.